# Nullable of nullable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a use case where I need double level of nullable, something like `x: SomeClass??`. See `prefetchedRecord` argument in java code below

```
public Optional<SomeClass> fetchRecord(Long id) {
   ...
}

public void process(
    Long id,
    Optional<Optional<SomeClass>> prefetchedRecord
) {
  Optional<SomeClass> fetchedRecord = prefetchedResult.orElseGet( () -> fetchRecord(id) )
  if (fetchedRecord.isPresent()) { ... process ... }
  else { ... do something else ... }
}
```

So for the `prefetchedRecord` the inner optional signifies the result of the fetching and the outer optional shows whether the fetching was ever done before calling the `process` function. I use two optional to avoid refetching the record even if the fetching returned nothing.

How would you write this in Kotlin? I realize using double optional is not that clear and I could use a custom class instead, smth like

```
data class FetchResult<T>(val result: T, val fetched: boolean)
```

but I wonder if there is something built in into Kotlin to support this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do nullable of nullable in Kotlin. I think Kotlin way is avoid null in most cases. You can use sealed-classes for more expressive code.

For example:

```
sealed class Result<out T> {
    data class Fetched<T>(val result: T): Result<T>()
    data class Prefetched<T>(val result: T): Result<T>()
    object None: Result<Nothing>()
}
```

[Sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) provides algebraic data types support and you can make very expressive types with this powerful language feature.
You also can use Kotlin standard [Result](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/) in some cases

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. Just to double check, your custom sealed class `Result` has nothing to do with the standard `Result` class right? I should actually name it something else?

Comment: Yeah, my Result has has nothing to do with the standard `Result`. But you could leave this name if you want or maybe find better name for you case

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing built-in in **Kotlin** to handle your requirements. If you are targeting **Java** platform you can use `java.util.Optional<T>` class:

```
fun process(id: Long, prefetchedRecord: Optional<Optional<SomeClass>>) {
    ...
}
```

Or you can try to use `java.util.Optional<T>` class like this:

```
fun process(id: Long, prefetchedRecord: Optional<SomeClass>?) {
    ...
}
```